# FastReport ficando doido com string numerica

Tags: delphi, fast-reports

Gosto muito do FastReport pela inúmeras opções de layout que podemos fazer nele, mas confesso que as vezes ele me da nos nervos e se eu pudesse trocava.

Estou inserindo a seguinte string num campo Memo:

```
    MemoExames.Lines.Add(Copy(<frxDBDatasetAPExames."codigo_tuss">+'00000000', 1,8)
      +' - '+Format('%-40s', [<frxDBDatasetAPExames."nome_tecnico">])
      +' '+DateToStr(<frxDBDatasetAPExames."data_ven">));
```

O resultado deveria ser:

```
00000000 - EXAME CLÍNICO - ASO                      28/03/2012
```

Mas ele insiste em colocar

```
EXAME CLÍNICO - ASO                      28/03/2012 - 00000000
```

Ele esta entendendo que zeros tem que ir a direita... se eu trocar 0 por X ele formata corretamente, mas se for numero ele insiste sozinho em colocar na direita, ja tentei de tudo, mas o maldito não me obedece

Alguém ja passou por isso?

Comment: Não tenho como testar aqui, mas se puder sugerir algo, dê uma olhada nas propriedades do memo.. tem algo como `HideZeros`.. também outra propriedade que suprime caracteres repetidos e outras que podem estar gerando a situação acima.

Comment: @Andrey, era a propriedade RTLReading, caraca, que tempo que perdi nesse troço... sua resposta deu uma clareada.